# How get the echo from PHP to Swift UIAlertController

Tags: php, swift

It's almost a day since I'm working on my Login page of my App and I want to show to my app the errors (or whatever from the echo of PHP) to my xCode app. I'll show you my PHP file and my xCode

```php
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{

 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];

 if($password == '' || $email == '')
 {
    echo 'Please fill all values.';
 }
 else
 {
    require_once('GBconnect.php');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password' OR mobile_no='$email' AND password='$password'";
    $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connection,$sql));

        if(isset($check))
        {  
            echo 'Login Success';
        }
        else
        { 
            echo 'Email/Phone or Password is wrong.';
        }
        mysqli_close($connection);
 }
}
else
{
    echo 'error';
}
```

Here's my Swift file:

```
@IBAction func signUp(_ sender: Any)
{
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://34.205.37.201/restapi/GBlogin3.php")! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let logEmail = "email=\(username.text!)&& password=\(password.text!)"
    let logMobile = "mobile_no=\(username.text!)&& password=\(password.text!)"

    if (username.text?.isEmpty)! || (password.text?.isEmpty)!
    {
        //display message
        LoginInfoMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "Please input your Email or Phone and Password.");
    }
    if let checkNum = Int(username.text!)
    {
        print(checkNum)
        request.httpBody = logMobile.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    }

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)
    {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
        }

        print("response = \(String(describing: response))") 
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
    }
    task.resume()

    username.text = ""
    password.text = ""
    return
```

Comment: What result are you seeing now?  You should also take a look at https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire, a very good library for handling network requests in Swift

Comment: `$password = $_POST['password'];` -> then we see no encryption ? On PHP side, you should **not** store plain text password, but rather use PHP built-in `password_hash / password_verify`

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I see:

1. You specify `logEmail` but never use it anywhere
2. You have a space in `logMobile` but you should not when using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST data
3. In a related item, you should use a more robust form encoding than concatenating strings.
4. You should use HTTP status codes to indicate success or failure, not strings.  Use HTTP 200 for success, HTTP 401 for needing credentials, and HTTP 403 for invalid credentials

With all of that said, you haven't specified what you are seeing when you run the code.  If you can do that, we can offer more specific advice.  Use [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com) to verify that your server side works correctly, then you can ensure your client is working with the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can encoding the response then unwrap in source app to handle the different messages.

```
<?php
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if($password != '' || $email != ''){
$check = false; //Your connection

if($check){  
    echo json_encode([
        "Message" => "Login Success",
        "Status" => "Ok"
    ]);
}
else{ 
    echo json_encode([
        "Message" => "Email/Phone or Password is wrong.",
        "Status" => "Error"
    ]);
}
}
?>
```

And then

```
@IBAction func signup(_ sender: Any) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/chava/login.php")! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let logEmail = "email=\(emial.text!) && password=\(password.text!)"
    print(logEmail)
    if (emial.text?.isEmpty)! || (password.text?.isEmpty)!{
        print("Please input your Email or Phone and Password.");
    }
    request.httpBody = logEmail.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil{
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
        }else{
            //print(String(data:data!,encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
            if let resp = data {
                do{
                    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: resp) as! [String:AnyObject]
                    if let message = jsonResult["Message"]{
                        print(message)
                    }
                }catch{

                }
            }
        }

        //print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
        //let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        //print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
    }
```

I hope help you !